# Add increase number while query data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I want to query data with sample column (No. column) like this (assumpt we have 5 records):

```
No.
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I get the result like this column?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [row_number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function to get numeric sequence starting from 1.

Example:

```
select *, row_numer() over (order by field1) as Seq from customtable
```

You can specify any field for order by clause in `row_number`

Comment: @user3011414 if you find any answer on your question useful and has satisfied your request kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT No,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY No) AS rn  FROM table
```

[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12bde/1)